# Как установить ограничение по времени на выполнение exec python?

Tags: python, telegram, exec, eval

У меня в коде python есть выполнение exec('*какой-то код*') и мне надо добавить ограничение по времени на выполнение кода в exec() например на 1 секунду. Т.е. если код внутри не успел выполниться, то программа продолжает работать, но уже сам код внутри exec() не выполняет.

Comment: Выполнять в отдельном потоке/процессе с ограничением жизни (например https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/22/how-not-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-computation-in-python). А так, если вы используете exec/eval с текстом от пользователя, то позаботьтесь о проверках значения, чтобы не получить от юзера код, который например удалит файлы из компа

Comment: exec не стоит использовать вообще никогда

Comment: про опасность exec/eval https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/

Answer (score 1):

```py
import signal

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception("Timed out!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
signal.alarm(10)   # Ten seconds
try:
    long_function_call()
except Exception, msg:
    print("Timed out!")
```